# Correct use of "but", "however" and "although"

Tags: word-choice, differences, conjunctions

I am not sure which conjunction to use in the following context:

> 1. I know about programming **but** I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming.
> 2. I know about programming **although** I have a little bit of confusion in programming.
> 3. I know about programming **however** I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your sentences #1 and #2 are both correct, so long as you add a comma after "programming":

> I know about programming, [but/although] I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming.

In almost all situations *but* and *although* are synonyms. *Although* is slightly more formal, and is preferred if you want to stress that both halves of your statement may be true. *But* is used when you wish to stress contradiction between the halves of the statement. For example:

> She said the book was blue, but I think that it's green. [Contradiction: prefer *but*.]
>
> Usually we speak in English, although we sometimes use Russian. [Both halves are true: prefer *although*.]

Note that this is not a firm rule, since you could use either *but* or *although* in both of the sentences above without it being wrong.

*However* is a different matter. *However* is an adverb, and it's used to introduce a new sentence in circumstances where you would otherwise use *but* to join the sentences. So your example #3 should be:

> I know about programming. However, I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming.

(Final note: "a little bit confusion" is grammatically incorrect. You need to add the word "of": *a little bit **of** confusion*.)

Comment: In this case, the same way `but` and `although` need to be preceeded by a comma, `however` can stay if it's preceeded by a semicolon.

Comment: @JSB +1 for the final note correction.

Comment: *But* and *although* are **not**  synonymous.

Comment: It is *but* and *however* that are semantically equivalent.

Comment: "Although" can also be used in the beginning of the sentence: `Although I have a little bit of confusion in programming, I know about programming.`

Comment: @JSBձոգչ Could you help me to figure out why in the following example "but" used instead of, I dunno, let's say "and":  "_An icon is a simple but effective way to make your app stand out._"
Taken from [ionicframework.com](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/adding-an-icon/)

Comment: Because I don't see any contradiction here. The first part is *simple* which leads to a positive outcome, the second part is *effective* which also leads to a positive outcome!

Answer (score 1):

Sentence #2 is correct as it is written.
Sentence #1 needs a comma.
Sentence #3 needs to be separated into two clauses. This can be done with a period or a semicolon.

Sentence #1 uses *but*, which is a coordinating conjunction. When two independent clauses are joined with a coordinating conjunction, a comma should be added to separate both parts of the compound sentence.

1. I know about programming, but I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming.

Sentence #2 is correct as it is. As noted by SF, *although* can be used at the beginning of the sentence. If the two clauses are reversed, the sentence will require a comma. As it is now, the sentence does not require a comma. Here is the basic rule for combining two clauses with a subordinating conjunction such as *although*: if the sentence begins with the conjunction, add a comma in the middle; if the subordinating conjunction is in the middle of the sentence, no comma is needed.

2a. I know about programming although I have a little bit of confusion about Java programming.

2b. Although I have a little bit of confusion in Java programming, I know about programming.

Sentence 3 uses *however*. *However* is a conjunctive adverb. There are a few ways to use *however* correctly, but it cannot be a substitute for *but*.  The easy solution is to separate the two clauses with a period or a semicolon, and begin the second clause with
the conjunctive adverb.

3a. I know about programming. However, I have a little bit of confusion about Java programming.

3b. I know about programming; however, I have a little bit of confusion about Java programming.

Some conjunctive adverbs, such as *however*, can be used another way. The clauses still need to be separated, but *however* does not always have to begin the second clause. It can often be "worked in" to the second clause next to the main action verb. This is usually more fluent when an auxiliary verb such as *do* is present.

3c. I know about programming; I do, however, have a little bit of confusion about Java programming.